# Missing operation for soapAction "" and body element "" with soap version 1.1 BW6

Tags: xml, soap, soapui, fault, tibco-business-works

I'm invoking Soap service via invoke activity with a reference binding, in the binding tab I'm using soapui Mock parameters (host, port : in the http client  and URI), when debugging I'm  facing this error :

```
[Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog.

11:15:58.805 ERROR [bwEngThread:In-Memory Process Worker-5] com.tibco.bw.core - TIBCO-BW-CORE-500050: The BW process [Applications.DOM_OPALE.CLOE.CreationBondecommande.CreationBonDeCommande_1-SOAPExtClient] instance faulted, JobId [bw0a102], ProcessInstanceId [bw0a102], ParentProcessInstanceId [bw0a101], Module [ProcessorBusinessShared:1.0.0.0], Application [CloeAdapterOut.application:1.0]. 

   <CausedBy> TIBCO-BW-CORE-500052: Invoke activity [CreationBonDeCommande] fault. 

   <CausedBy> com.tibco.bw.binding.soap.DefaultFault: TIBCO-BW-BINDING-SOAP-550100: Received SOAP Fault from the service provider of the Operation [{OPA}CreationBonDeCommande], SoapReferenceBinding [SOAPReferenceBinding], Application [CloeAdapterOut.application:1.0].  SOAP Fault received: [<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <soapenv:Fault>
            <faultcode>Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Missing operation for soapAction [rpc/OPA:CreationBonDeCommande] and body element [CreationBonDeCommande] with SOAP Version [SOAP 1.1]</faultstring>
        </soapenv:Fault>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
]
```

any idea please ?

Below is the wsdl file:

```xml
<message name="CreationBonDeCommande_Input">
    <part name="InputMessage" type="xsdLocal0:InputTopElmtData"/>
</message>
<message name="CreationBonDeCommande_Output">
    <part name="OutputMessage" type="xsdLocal1:OutputTopElmtData"/>
</message>

<portType name="OPA_CreationBonDeCommande">
    <operation name="CreationBonDeCommande">
        <input message="tns:CreationBonDeCommande_Input"/>
        <output message="tns:CreationBonDeCommande_Output"/>
    </operation>

</portType>

<binding name="OPA_CreationBonDeCommande" type="tns:OPA_CreationBonDeCommande">
    <soap:binding style="rpc" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="CreationBonDeCommande">
        <soap:operation soapAction="rpc/OPA:CreationBonDeCommande" />
        <input>
            <soap:body namespace="OPA" use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body namespace="OPA" use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>
<service name="OPA_CreationBonDeCommande_WS">
    <port binding="tns:OPA_CreationBonDeCommande" name="OPA_CreationBonDeCommande">
        <soap:address location="http://<web_server></web_server>/eai_fra/start.swe?SWEExtSource=WebService&amp;SWEExtCmd=Execute&amp;UserName=sadmin&amp;Password=sadmin"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tibco BW 6.3.2 remove the header that contains soapAction due to a bug--> upgrading  version to 6.3.3 , the problem is fixed

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that the request is missing `soapAction` header based on the fault message.

Please add the `soapAction` with appropriate value.

Comment: the problem is the soap Action exists in the wsdl

Comment: Well, the request has to have it.

Comment: I'm using Tibco BW 6 I'm just mapping the input message I think this generated automatically

Comment: Is your client also in `tibco-bw`?

Comment: In fact the problem is a bug with BW 6.3.2 after upgrading to 6.3.3 the stack is fixed

Comment: Oh, ok. glad to know.

Comment: Please add the soapAction with appropriate value. - C# is making this extremely difficult. It should be as simple as client.Header = whatever but instead it's some kind of evil monstrosity involving about 20 lines of code!